Questions about radio antennas
I need to know a few things about radio antennas.

As per the theory, the length of any antenna works best if it's length is exactly the same as the wavelength. With that said, if I need to build an antenna for HF frequency of 2 MHz, then the length should be 140/2 = 70 m. So, taking a long wire of 70 m would be able to receive the 2 MHz. But what if I wind the wire on a 1 inch pipe and make a loop of several turns. Would it work that way?

How do I know the bandwidth of any resonant antenna? For instance, if I use a whip antenna of 70 cm then it's going to work for (140/0.7)/4 = 50 MHz. But is it also going to receive upto 108 MHz? I have seen that a longer antenna is able to receive higher frequencies but a shorter antenna can't receive lower frequencies. So, how do I know the correct frequency range of an antenna?

Which type of antenna is better for VHF---whip, loop, or dipole?

A loop antenna can receive brands from HF to UHF. So, can it be considered as a wideband antenna like a discone?

How small can we create a loop antenna for FM reception?


Take a look at the YouTube video on the link below.
That engineer has made a very small loop antenna. But what is the formula to calculate the loop length and the capacitor?

Usually, the gap between a dipole should be between 1-2 cm. But what will happen if the gap is less than 1 cm?

I have seen people making magloop antenna using coaxial cable but a coax has a protective shield around the inner core wire. So, howcome it's going to receive the signal?

Does the gauge of the wire have anything to do with the loop antenna's efficiency?

Why do most antennas like Yagi, are made of aluminium instead of copper? In what ways aluminium is better than copper being less conductive than copper?



This is way too many questions for one question, but I'll focus on one important part.
For a receiving antenna, resonance is not very important at all. Below its resonant frequency, an antenna gets less sensitive, but that's about it. It can still be perfectly useful down to one-tenth of its resonant frequency, or even less, depending on the application. Above its resonant frequency, the antenna's impedance will be quite variable, and so will its directional pattern, but in many cases that's not important. So a receiving antenna is good over several orders of magnitude. I can use my 160m-circumference horizontal loop to listen to SSB conversations on 144MHz. And my 1m-diameter LZ1AQ loop receives very well on 1.8MHz — it just needs a preamplifier at the antenna to make up for its low sensitivity and mostly-reactive impedance.

your answer is not quite clear.  To get a simplified answer---whether a whip antenna for 100 MHz (needs to be (140/100)/4 = 0.35 or 35 cm ) will able to receive frequencies above 100 MHz or not if the antenna is not shortened? Most pocket FM radio receivers come with a 30 cm telescopic antenna but how it will able to receive frequencies below 100 MHz upto 88 MHz without increasing the antenna length?

@user10897549 the answer very directly answers the questions you ask in the comment here.

No one knows anything here and giving excuses.

Antennas should be resonate. For a simple wire antenna like a dipole, you want each side of the dipole to be 1/4 of a wave length or half a wave length for the entire antenna. A vertical is usually 1/4 of a wavelength, but there is a ground plane that acts like another 1/4 of a wavelength.
As mentioned receiving antennas will work better is resonant, but will still work if not resonate, but they will be less sensitive. That is to say they will not pick up weaker signals.
Antennas for transmitting need to be close to resonate. If they are not resonate, part of the signal reflects back into the transmitter and can actually cause damage if the miss match is large enough.
In most cases we use the same antenna for receiving and for transmitting, so we want an antenna that is resonate or appear to the radio to be resonate.
There are many ways to make an antenna resonate besides just its length. Adding a inductive coil at the base of a vertical antenna or a capacitor at the top of vertical makes it appear to be longer in its wavelength. many whip antennas for mobile use will have such a loading coil at its base.
Other designs like a J pole or a Yagi have features known as matches that effectively modified wavelengths they work at.
End feed antennas are also popular. They use a matching transformer to connect the antenna to the radio.
We can also use antenna tuners that add various amounts of inductance and capacitance to make the antenna appear resonate.
Other antennas have certain properties we find advantageous. Yagis and loops are directional.
Most the methods and make an antenna appear resonate, do result in a less efficient antenna. We don't receive weakest signals and we lose some of radiated power, but such antennas are usually smaller making them more convenient to use.
